# Как организовать работу с прокси в Parallel.For

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl

Есть 5 прокси. Запрос с каждого прокси можно делать не более раза за 2 секунды. 
Есть список id. Вопрос, как запустить последовательно эти запросы, но в то же время ограничить выполнения с каждого прокси? Застопорился уже в самом начале

```
 Parallel.For(0, data.Count(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 }, (i) =>
            {
                using (HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest())
                {
                   req.Get("xxx.ru?param=data[i]");
                }
             }
```

Comment: Можно просто создать 5 Task'ов, внутри каждого цикл while с запросом и паузой в две секунды Task.Delay.

Comment: количество прокси у меня динамическое @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: @Radzhab пишу пример, у вас .NET Core?

Comment: нет, обычный net 4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, как с `Parallel.For` это сделать, но знаю как с `async`/`await`.

Для реализации таких многопоточных задач с фиксированным количеством потоков, лучше использовать кокурентную коллекцию на основе Produser/Consumer технологии. То есть, один поток может в эту коллекцию что-то кидать, другой как только в ней что-то появится, забирает это в работу. Один из вариантов таких коллекций - `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection`. Ее фишка в том, что пока она пустая, она блокирует поток ожиданием нового элемента.

Для того чтобы добиться максимальной производительности и использовать [TAP](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap), для сетeвых задач рекомендую `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. В .NET Core 3.1 кстати он тоже есть, и очень круто оптимизирован по производительности, точнее он враппер, а то, на чем он ездит, зависит от типа операционной системы и фреймворка.

Для того, чтобы слать запросы из одной очереди сразу в несколько проксей по принципу "кто успел - тот забрал в работу", можно использовать такой класс.

```csharp
// чтобы при обработке результатов было понятно, на какой именно запрос получен этот ответ
public struct JobResult
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
}

public class ProxyWorker
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts; // для остановки воркера
    public WebProxy Proxy { get; } // публично видимые настройки прокси

    public ProxyWorker(WebProxy proxy, BlockingCollection<string> jobs, BlockingCollection<JobResult> jobResults)
    {
        Proxy = proxy;
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // запускаем разгребание задач
        Task.Run(() => JobsConsumer(proxy, jobs, jobResults, _cts.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult());

        // или так можно
        //Task.Run(async () => await JobsConsumer(proxy, jobs, jobResults, _cts.Token));
    }

    private async Task JobsConsumer(BlockingCollection<string> jobs, BlockingCollection<JobResult> jobResults, CancellationToken token)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = Proxy }, true))
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string url in jobs.GetConsumingEnumerable(token))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // устанавливаем соединение с сервером и читаем заголовок ответа
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // бросить исключение, если 404, 403 и т.д.
                        Task<string> responseTask = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // запускаем асинхронно процесс скачивания ответа
                        await Task.Delay(2000, token).ConfigureAwait(false); // и засекаем 2 секунды
                        jobResults.Add(new JobResult() { Url = url, Result = await responseTask }); // если ответ еще не доехал, здесь его еще подождем
                    }
                    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        jobs.Add(url); // задача не выполнена, вернем ее в очередь
                        // быть может не стоит возвращать, или ограничить количество
                        // попыток, и если оно достигло порога, то не возвращать
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            { 
                // сюда попадаем, если вызван _cts.Cancel()
            }
            finally
            {
                _cts.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Shutdown() // остановить всё, завершить работу воркера
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

И всё это можно вот так использовать:

```csharp
// Создать рабочие коллекции
BlockingCollection<string> jobs = new BlockingCollection<string>();
BlockingCollection<JobResult> jobResults = new BlockingCollection<JobResult>();

// список воркеров
List<ProxyWorker> workers = new List<ProxyWorker>();

// добавить новый воркер
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://myproxy.net:3128");
ProxyWorker proxyWorker = new ProxyWorker(proxy, jobs, jobResults);
workers.Add(proxyWorker);

// найти воркер по настройкам прокси
ProxyWorker worker = workers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Proxy.Address.ToString() == "http://myproxy.net:3128");

// и если найден, то завершить и удалить из списка
if (worker != null)
{
    worker.Shutdown();
    workers.Remove(worker);
}

// или сразу все воркеры завершить
foreach (ProxyWorker worker in workers)
{
    worker.Shutdown();
}
workers.Clear();

// вот так можно закинуть в работу ваши данные
foreach (string elem in data)
{
    // пока они закидываются, прокси воркеры уже начали это пережевывать
    jobs.Add("xxx.ru?param=" + elem);
}

// а получать ответы можно вот так
int resultsCount = 0;
foreach (JobResult result in jobResults.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    // тело цикла будет выполняться по мере получения ответов
    // так что можно красиво обновлять статус их получения :)
    string s = result.Result; // что-то можно сделать с результатом

    resultsCount++;
    if (resultsCount == data.Count) break; // все ответы получены
}
```

В качестве бонуса здесь то, что оно уже поддерживает одновременное закидывание запросов в очередь и одновременное разгребание ответов. В вышеуказанном коде есть нерешенная проблема: если будет ошибочный `url`, то он будет циклично возвращаться в очередь, и работа никогда не завершится, комментарий в коде выше про это есть.

В общем, пробуйте, дорабатывайте под себя.